# How to access iframe checkbox elements

Tags: javascript

I have a web page that consists of a checkbox (parent) and on this same web page, I also have a iframe that is sourced from another page that displays a number of records, which also has a checkbox (children) against each record. If I tick the parent checkbox, I would like to cascade this through to all children checkboxs within the iframe as well as disable these children checkboxes.

How can I access the checkboxes within the iframe?

My iframe definition on the man page is similar to the following:

```
<iframe id="iframe1" src="'+URL+'" style="border:none;width:799px;height:200px;" frameborder="1" framespacing="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay here is an example...

First here is the source for the iFrame contents (I called it FramePage.htm)...

```
<body>
    <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox"  name="checkbox" /> 
    <input id="Checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/>
    <input id="Checkbox3" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
</body>
```

Here is the source on the page that houses the iFrame...

```
<iframe id="frame" src="FramePage.htm"></iframe>

<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="setData()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function setData()
    {
        var frame = document.getElementById('frame');

        var checkboxes = frame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByName('checkbox');

        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
        {
            checkboxes[i].checked = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Clicking the button on the parent page will select all the checkboxes with the name 'checkboxes' on the frame page.

Hope this helps **:)**

Comment: Thanks for that Chalkey - I will try it out. BTW, I also need to disable the checkbox within the iframe as well - would that just be checkboxes[i].disabled = true ?

Comment: Off the top of my head i think it would be checkboxes[i].checked = false; I think disable would disable the control not the value... :)

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful: a jquery plugin to [easily access the iframe document](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/05/14/jquery-edge-better-support-for-other-windows-and-documents). That is, if its not cross domain like peter said.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL of the iframe src is not in the same domain as the parent, there could be cross-domain security issues that prevent manipulation via JavaScript, as per the same-origin policies.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly well

```
$("#select_checkbox").change(function(event){
    $("#content").contents().find(':checkbox').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).attr('checked', $("#select_checkbox").is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

where select_checkbox is the id of the parent checkbox, content is the id of the frame