# Javascript/jQuery Change variable of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have a webpage that I want to connect though an `IFRAME`. There is a checkbox on the page which I need to change the value of.

My `IFRAME` is connecting to:

```
<iframe id="intranet" src="http://webmail.ucn.dk" width="100%" height="90%"></iframe>
```

Here's the checkbox:

```
<input id="chkBsc" name="chkBsc" type="checkbox" class="rdo" onclick="clkBsc()" value="1" disabled="">
```

This one as well...

```
<input id="chkBsc" name="chkBsc" type="checkbox" class="rdo" onclick="clkBsc()" value="1" enabled="">
```

I'm really stuck with this problem, I hope someone can guide me through to solve it.
I read somewhere on the internet that Ii can change the variable with a jQuery but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Is the checkbox in your iFrame?

Comment: I've refined the question ;)

Comment: yea its a checbox, i want make it enabled. i could do it with chrome and exploer with changing it from disabled to enabled, but how to send it with paramater?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043786/how-to-access-iframe-checkbox-elements

Comment: You can't modify the content of the iframe due to Same Origin Policy. There are work arounds but you need the third party to cooperate.

Comment: okay but thing i cant change is at end of the code, is enabled and disabled, its not the value = true or false,