# How to create a text area with checkbox in MVC view?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, textarea

kindly refer the below screenshot for it.I need to create a control similar to it which has multiple checkbox and has scroll bar well.Kindly suggest if it can be done using bootstrap.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What keeps you from using a HTML form/your MVC frameworks form helper? You cannot create forms with bootstrap, bootstrap only adds styling to them! On top, the text right of the check boxes are labels, no text fields. You can add a scrollbar with `overflow: scroll;` in your css.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most logical way that this is done is through an Iframe with checkboxes then formatted to size with css/jquery

something like this:
[How to Access iFrame Checkbox Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043786/how-to-access-iframe-checkbox-elements)